# Flutter Firestore function not returning aggregate value of counter

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have set up a distributed counter of likes and want to count the total likes in the distributed counter.

The counter is set up under a my "posts" model as a subcollection of "count_shrads" that includes three documents (1, 2, 3) that each have a "count" field. I want to create a function in flutter that returns the total of these count fields across each of the three documents for a given article.

```
Future getTotal(postID) async {
    int counter;
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('post').document(postID).collection('count_shrads')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) =>
        data.documents.forEach((doc) => counter += (doc["count"])));
    print("The total is $counter");
    return counter;
  }
```

This is currently returning null. Anyone know how I can return the aggregate value?

---

Using the reduce function:

```
Future getTotal(postID) async {
    int value;
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('post').document(postID).collection('count_shrads')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) =>
        data.documents.reduce((value, element) => value + doc["count"])
    );
    return value;
  }
```

---

Adding picture of data model in Firestore.[image]

Comment: Just like in JS, you might use the reduce() function : `iterable.reduce((value, element) => value + element)`. The sum of shards counters will be the accumulator : https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html

Also you spelled shards "shrads", be carful

Comment: @Firebaser thanks! can you help explain the implementation more? I added the above code but that's providing errors. How do I capture the shards counters?

Comment: Try `'count_shards'` inszead of `'count_shrads'`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I realize I misspelled this in Firestore and plan to go back to change, but, as I added in pic above, this is current spelling, so shouldn't impact that?

Comment: Oh, I missed that it's spelled that way in the database as well. I haven't used datastote and can't help you here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the result of an async call, you need to wait for the result to become available

```
Future getTotal(postID) async {
    int counter;
    await Firestore.instance // <<<== changed
        .collection('post').document(postID).collection('count_shrads')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) =>
        data.documents.forEach((doc) => counter += (doc["count"])));
    print("The total is $counter");
    return counter;
  }
}
```

Without `await` `return counter;` is executed immediately and `counter += ...` is much later executed when the response from the Firebase server arrives. `await` ensures that the code below only executes after the `Future` returned from the async call is completed (execution done or error happened)

Comment: Thanks! However, this still doesn't seem to be working and will return null. In Android Studio the "await" is underlined with the message "Await only futures". I also confirmed that my database is structured as outlined above so not worried about spelling or reference issues. Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Check if `forEach(...)` is executed at all

Comment: Appreciate the help. It doesn't appear the forEach is getting run when I add print statements. I posted the data model for reference above and believe I'm calling that correctly, but would love any advice.